# cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'linkedin:config' is not complete

Tags: linkedin-api, connector

i respect the tutorial of cloud connector which is LinkedIn connector and i implement it on Mule Studio and there is no error but it appears on me a failed notification .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try pasting the XML config of your app, or at least the config of the LinkedIn global element?